# Problem with arrows in feynmp-auto

Tags: arrows, feynmp-auto

I was trying to put a momentum arrow alogn with the photon propagator for which I had to define a new command called "marrow" but it's showing the name "marrows" in the diagram and I don't know why. Here's the code

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\newcommand{\marrow}[5]{%
    \fmfcmd{style_def marrow#1
    expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 #2 withpen pencircle scaled 0.4;
    label.#3(btex #4 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted 12 #2);
    enddef;}
    \fmf{marrow#1,tension=0}{#5}}


\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{dm22}{marrows}
    \begin{equation}
        \parbox{100pt}{
        \begin{fmfgraph*}(100,50) 
            \fmfleft{i1}
            \fmfright{o1}
            \fmf{photon}{i1,o1}
            \fmfdot{i1,o1}
            \fmfv{label=$\nu$,label.angle=-70}{i1}
            \fmfv{label=$\mu$,label.angle=-100}{o1}
            \marrow{c}{down}{lft}{$p$}{i1,o1}
        \end{fmfgraph*}} \quad : \quad i\tilde{D}_F^{\mu\nu}(p)
    \end{equation}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment `fmffile` doesn't take a second argument. So, if you delete the `{marrows}` part from the line

```tex
\begin{fmffile}{dm22}{marrows}
```

then the extra text with "marrows" will disappear.

Comment: Okay but if I delete it then it's not going to use it and it's not going to show me the arrow in the diagram which is what I want in the end, isn't it?

Comment: I've just realized that it works no matter if you put marrows or not. It's just a name, the important thing is the command \marrow inside \fmffile @gz839918